# Suspend and Resume thread (Windows, C)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I'm currently developing a heavily multi-threaded application, dealing with lots of small data batch to process.

The problem with it is that too many threads are being spawns, which slows down the system considerably. In order to avoid that, I've got a table of Handles which limits the number of concurrent threads. Then I "WaitForMultipleObjects", and when one slot is being freed, I create a new thread, with its own data batch to handle.

Now, I've got as many threads as I want (typically, one per core). Even then, the load incurred by multi-threading is extremely sensible. The reason for this: the data batch is small, so I'm constantly creating new threads.

The first idea I'm currently implementing is simply to regroup jobs into longer serial lists. Therefore, when I'm creating a new thread, it will have 128 or 512 data batch to handle before being terminated. It works well, but somewhat destroys granularity.

I was asked to look for another scenario: if the problem comes from "creating" threads too often, what about "pausing" them, loading data batch and "resuming" the thread?

Unfortunately, I'm not too successful.
The problem is: when a thread is in "suspend" mode, "WaitForMultipleObjects" does not detect it as available. In fact, I can't efficiently distinguish between an active and suspended thread.

So I've got 2 questions:

1. How to detect "suspended thread", so that i can load new data into it and resume it?
2. Is it a good idea? After all, is "CreateThread" really a ressource hog?

**Edit**

After much testings, here are my findings concerning Thread Pooling and IO Completion Port, both advised in this post.

Thread Pooling is tested using the older version "QueueUserWorkItem".
IO Completion Port requires using CreateIoCompletionPort, GetQueuedCompletionStatus and PostQueuedCompletionStatus;

1) First on performance : Creating many threads is very costly, and both thread pooling and io completion ports are doing a great job to avoid that cost. I am now down to 8-jobs per batch, from an earlier 512-jobs per batch, with no slowdown. This is considerable. Even when going to 1-job per batch, performance impact is less than 5%. Truly remarkable.

From a performance standpoint, QueueUserWorkItem wins, albeit by such a small margin (about 1% better) that it is almost negligible.

2) On usage simplicity : 
Regarding starting threads : No question, QueueUserWorkItem is by far the easiest to setup. IO Completion port is heavyweight in comparison.
Regarding ending threads : Win for IO Completion Port. 
For some unknown reason, MS provides no function in C to know when all jobs are completed with QueueUserWorkItem. It requires some nasty tricks to successfully implement this basic but critical function. There is no excuse for such a lack of feature.

3) On resource control : **Big win** for IO Completion Port, which allows to finely tune the number of concurrent threads, while there is no such control with QueueUserWorkItem, which will happily spend all CPU cycles from all available cores. That, in itself, could be a deal breaker for QueueUserWorkItem.
Note that newer version of Completion Port seems to allow that control, but are only available on Windows Vista and later.

4) On compatibility : small win for IO Completion Port, which is available since Windows NT4. QueueUserWorkItem only exists since Windows 2000. This is however good enough. Newer version of Completion Port is a no-go for Windows XP.

As can be guessed, I'm pretty much tied between the 2 solutions. They both answer correctly to my needs. 
For a general situation, I suggest I/O Completion Port, mostly for resource control.
On the other hand, QueueUserWorkItem is easier to setup. Quite a pity that it loses most of this simplicity on requiring the programmer to deal alone with end-of-jobs detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to also support Windows XP, you cannot use CreateThreadpool -- otherwise, if Vista and newer is sufficient, Windows thread pools are the easiest way.

If Windows XP support is needed, spawn a number of threads and assign them to an [IO completion port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx), then have each thread block on GetQueuedCompletionStatus(). Completion ports let you post events to the port which will wake exactly one thread per event, and they are very efficient. They use a LIFO strategy on waking threads to keep caches warm, too.

In any case, you will **never** want to suspend a thread. Never ever. Block, wait, but don't suspend.

The reason is that with suspend you get the problem that you describe, plus you will create deadlocks, e.g. if your thread is within a critical section or mutex. Aside from a debugger, nobody should ever need to suspend a thread.

Comment: Very good point. Yes, Windows XP support is a necessity (although i primarily develop under Win7, so i have to do some tests under XP sometimes to ensure compatibility). I heard about IO Completion port a few months ago. I just understood it was nice and speedy, but well, that's not enough to properly get it; i'll have a look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: Completion ports look scary at first, but they are pretty simple. Create one with NULL as the "existing" parameter, that gives you a handle to the completion port. Pass that to all threads that you create. Then, in each thread, create a completion port _again_, but this time pass the handle in as the "existing" parameter. That's it, now you can use PostQueuedCompletionStatus from your main thread and GetQueuedCompletionStatus from your worker threads. The docs on MSDN are very complete, definitively worth a read.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanations. This is definately worth a try.

Comment: For anyone reading this, the above advice is inaccurate. Suspending thread is very beneficial in certain cases (although in OPs case, thread pools are indeed better). There is even a common object called a Fiber which is built to do this. Fibers are supported all the way back to Windows XP as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers

Answer (score 4):

Instead of implementing your own, consider using [CreateThreadpool()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682456%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The OS will do the work for you, and you don't have to worry about getting it right.

Comment: Sounds like a good advise; however, my current code is fairly simple, and i understand how it works. ThreadPools, on the other hand, look mysterious and complex. Maybe all i need is a simple example, since the one provided by Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686980%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is really frightening.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a fair amount of overhead involved with CreateThread.  One solution is to use a thread pool, [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684957%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Another is to just start a set of threads and have them retrieve a 'job item' from a thread-safe queue.

Comment: Yes, same comment : this could be a good way to handle my situation. But ThreadPools look complex to use. Any simple example around ?

Comment: I'm currently trying to use "QueueUserWorkItem", as it looks simple enough. However, i'm not finding any way to "wait for the pool" to complete the assigned job. It just seems that "QueueUserWorkItem" would gladly accept any new job without ever waiting for a slot to be freed.

Comment: It does. Create your own event, set it in the worker when it is done.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Any example ?

Comment: Use CreateEvent() and SetEvent().

Comment: OK , thanks for your comments. I can now create an event, and also wait for it to be set. The problem is, i don't know how to make sure i set the event only when *all* jobs are completed. I can certainly put the "set" as a last job, or the last part of the last job, but this does not guarantee that there is no other unfinished job ongoing. I'm still missing something here...

Comment: Use WaitForMultipleObjects().  And pay a visit to your local library, there's no good reason to get stuck on the basics like this.

Comment: Don't get angry. WaitForMultipleObjects() is the function i was using up to now, and i would have been using it gladly if i knew it was compatible with QueueUserWorkItem. The problem is, this function needs to get an array of handles as parameters. But where is the handle array when using QueueUserWorkItem ? The online documentation of MS is pretty scarce on this function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's almost as if they were unwilling for programmers to use it.

Comment: Little comment : it seems that QueueUserWorkItem works well under windows XP. From a performance standpoint, this method works well. I wouldn't say that i can go down to "one data batch" without a performance penalty, but i can certainly go down to batch of 4 or 8. This is a great step forward compared to previous requirement of 512 (due to thread creation overhead). Now, all i need is to be sure to wait for all jobs to be completed (even with the signal event, i've got sometimes one unfinished job). WaitForMultipleObjects() can certainly help, if only i knew where is the handle array...

Comment: OK, i've got it right, finally. I've complemented the event wait, which roughly takes me near the end of job completion, with a verification loop which checks some fields dedicated to end of job signaling, using a Sleep(0) between 2 checks; It works. There is a slight performance penalty due to Sleep(0) relinquishing up to 10ms before next try, but it works. However, it looks ugly, like a hack. I have to stress that i don't feel it normal to go after such strange algorithm just to check an end of job. It seems MS simply forgot an obvious C API Call, WaitForAll, which is provided in c# & C++

Comment: WaitHandle.WaitAll() as available in C# calls WaitForMultipleObjects().  Nothing was forgotten here.  Please close your question.

Comment: I've edited my question, since there is many elements to share. In a nutshell, *QueueUserWorkItem* is missing 2 importants features in my opinion, which are : 1) Resource control, to limit the number of concurrent threads, and 2) A comprehensive method to control that all jobs are completed. I've been looking for this second item pretty thoroughly, and all methods i've seen so far are either heavy (spawning myriads of events, using interlocked counters, etc.) or even downright hackish-styled (looping on counter, etc.) I/O completion ports answer both issues, but are more complex.